# Aligning to previous centered text

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

Is there any trick (or non-trick) for aligning left-adjusted text to wherever the center-adjusted sentence above it happens to begin?  Where the above sentence length cannot be predicted?

EDIT: reiterating the question:
I have a line of text that is centered.  The first letter of that line falls at some particular place on-screen, depending on how long the line happens to be.

I have a second line below it.  I wish for the first letter of that line to line up to the first letter of the previous line.  Simply centering it will obviously not do because the length may not be, and probably is not, the same.

Comment: What do you want to ask?

Comment: You need to provide more specific details about what you're trying to do. I'm sure this all makes perfect sense to you because you know what you want, but it is a bit abstract to the rest of us. ;)

Comment: I've elaborated in the 1st post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use text-align css property:

```
text-align:left;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't center the text, just use

```
p{
margin-left:  100px/*Or whatever number you want*/
}
```

and then all the text will be in line